# How to setError() on EditText fields that dont meet the requirements

Tags: java, android

I am currently in the process of making my first high school Android App project.
The App is basically a pressure calculator where the user enters 2 numbers (force and area) and the output is the pressure (force/area) displayed in certain pressure units such as Bar, Pascal and mmHg.
That part is working fine, when I enter certain numbers I get the result that is correct.
The problem is when I want to setError() on EditText fields that dont meet the next requirements: 1. The input field is 0 (cant divide with 0) and 2. The field is empty.
I have written code that prevents the app from crashing but doesnt properly set the error indicator on all fields that dont meet the criteria.
For an example, in this image although both of the fields are empty, I only get the error indicator on the 1st field and not the both: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXXQj.png
Or here, where one of the fields is empty and the other has a zero but only the empty field gets an indicator (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pD63.png).
Here is the code from MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.app_calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tvTitle, tvForce, tvSA, tvOutput, tvPascal, tvBar, tvmmHg;
        EditText etForce, etSA;

        Button button;

       tvTitle=findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
       tvForce=findViewById(R.id.tvForce);
       tvSA=findViewById(R.id.tvSA);
       tvOutput=findViewById(R.id.tvOutput);
       tvPascal=findViewById(R.id.tvPascal);
       tvBar=findViewById(R.id.tvBar);
       tvmmHg=findViewById(R.id.tvmmHg);

       etForce=findViewById(R.id.etForce);
       etSA=findViewById(R.id.etSA);


       button=findViewById(R.id.button);



button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {



        String force0 = etForce.getText().toString();
        String area0 = etSA.getText().toString();


        String errorMsg1 = getString(R.string.key_errorMsg1);
        String errorMsg2 = getString(R.string.key_errorMsg2);



        if(force0.isEmpty()){
            etForce.setError(errorMsg1);
            return;
        }

        if(area0.isEmpty()){
            etSA.setError(errorMsg1);
            return;
        }

        if(area0.matches("0")){
            etSA.setError(errorMsg2);
            return;
        }

        if(force0.matches("0")){
            etForce.setError(errorMsg2);
            return;
        }

        if(!force0.isEmpty() && !area0.isEmpty() && !force0.matches("0") && !area0.matches("0")){

        double force = Double.valueOf(force0);
        double area = Double.valueOf(area0);

        //Paskali
        double pascal = (double)force/area;
        tvPascal.setText(String.valueOf(pascal+" Pa"));


        //Bar
        double bar = pascal/100000;
        tvBar.setText(String.valueOf(bar+" Bar"));

        //mmHg

        double mmHg = pascal * 0.00750062;
        tvmmHg.setText(String.valueOf(mmHg+" mmHg"));
    }

    }
});



    }
}
```

I tried basically everything but have no clue how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the returns out of the individual ifs, and put it after the last check.  You want to run all the if statements to check all the error conditions.  The returns are making it leave the function after the first failure it finds.

Use a single return right before you do the calculations that may not have data.  That will prevent a crash or incorrect results from not being able to run the calculation, but still run all the checks.